# Get A Running Sum For Rep By Day

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, count, left-join

I am new to psql and wondering if I can get help with a query.

I have a current table that displays like this:

```
Index ID           Date Sent          Tag      Name     Tad ID      Cat
6   20306   "2020-09-18 12:02:58"   "9902"  "Michelle"  "9902"  "Servicing"
7   20510   "2020-08-27 11:23:01"   "9896"  "Jessica"   "9896"  "Servicing"
8   20582   "2020-09-21 15:24:25"   "9902"  "Michelle"  "9902"  "Servicing"
9   21196   "2020-07-22 11:42:10"   "9902"  "Michelle"  "9902"  "Servicing"
10  26548   "2020-08-03 15:16:26"   "9902"  "Michelle"  "9902"  "Servicing"
11  26924   "2020-08-28 15:49:29"   "9902"  "Michelle"  "9902"  "Servicing"
12  30310   "2020-09-24 09:44:06"   "9900"  "Godfrey"   "9900"  "Servicing"
```

I would like to have a running total of how many records each person (name) has in the last 30 days?

I know my current query probably isn't even close but I will still show you what I'm currently working with:

```
select date_sent, Count(Distinct id) as total_leads, name from finwell_leads
group by date_sent, name
```

This is what I would like to see:

```
"2020-10-01 12:02:58" Michelle 0
"2020-10-01 12:02:58" Jessica  1
"2020-10-01 12:02:58" Godfrey  0
"2020-10-02 12:02:58" Michelle 2
"2020-10-02 12:02:58" Jessica  1
"2020-10-02 12:02:58" Godfrey  1
"2020-10-05 12:02:58" Michelle 5
"2020-10-05 12:02:58" Jessica  3
"2020-10-05 12:02:58" Godfrey  1
"2020-10-06 12:02:58" Michelle 5
"2020-10-06 12:02:58" Jessica  4
"2020-10-06 12:02:58" Godfrey  1
"2020-10-07 12:02:58" Michelle 6
"2020-10-07 12:02:58" Jessica  5
"2020-10-07 12:02:58" Godfrey  2
```

How do I retrieve a running total of records by person by day?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired results do not seem consistent with your sample data. However, if I follow you correctly, you can cross join the distinct names with all dates of the period, then bring the table with a `left join`, and finally aggregate:

```
select d.dt, n.name, count(t.name) cnt
from (select distinct name from mytable) n
cross join generate_series(date '2020-01-01', date '2020-01-07', '1 day') d(dt)
left join mytable t 
    on  t.name = n.name
    and t.date_sent >= d.dt - interval '30 day'
    and t.date_sent <= d.dt
group by d.dt, n.name
```